# Zenity --progress return string and return code (POSIX shell)

Tags: shell, posix, zenity

I am trying to call a shell function and while this function processes, a zenity progress dialog should be displayed.
However, I want the echo'ed string from that function to be stored in a variable for further processing, as well as the return code of that function.

And all of this in POSIX shell.

My current approach is like this:

```
output="$( compress "${input}" |  \
    zenity --progress \
    --pulsate \
    --title="Compressing files" \
    --text="Scanning mail logs..." \
    --percentage=0 \
)";

if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
    echo "${output}"
    exit 1
fi
```

The progress dialog shows up, however, `$output` is empty at the end.

Any idea how to get the output of the `compress` function?

Answer (score 0):

`zenity` doesn't do that.  For a progress dialog, all that it returns to the environment is an exit-code.

You can see that in the source code:

- progress.c, near the end of the file, in [zenity_progress_dialog_response](https://github.com/GNOME/zenity/blob/master/src/progress.c#L372), calls
- [zenity_util_return_exit_code](https://github.com/GNOME/zenity/blob/master/src/util.c#L254), which is finally used in
- [main.c](https://github.com/GNOME/zenity/blob/master/src/main.c#L114)

The only *text* printed to your shell from `zenity` is the extra-button text.  It simply updates the GUI and discards the text of the progress messages, e.g., in [zenity_progress_update_time_remaining](https://github.com/GNOME/zenity/blob/master/src/progress.c#L104)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subshell and run commands in there. The only caveat is that the commands executed after the progress dialog is finished aren't allowed to write to standard output. Otherwise you get an I/O error.

In your case this would look like this:

```
(
    output="$(compress "${input}")"

    if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
        #echo "${output}" <- this would result in an I/O error because the pipe is closed
        # write to somewhere else, maybe standard error like so:
        echo "${output}" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
) | \
    zenity --progress \
    --pulsate \
    --title="Compressing files" \
    --text="Scanning mail logs..." \
    --percentage=0
```

I used this to create a small "GUI" wrapper to sha256sum, like so:

```
(
  HASH=$(sha256sum "$1")
  # send EOF to end the zenity progress dialog
  exec 1>&-
  zenity --title="sha256sum" --info --text="$HASH" --no-wrap
) | zenity --progress  --title="sha256sum" --pulsate --auto-close --no-cancel
```